# Choice between two macros -- \doifemptyelse -- ConTeXT

Tags: context

I wanted to create a macro that outputs "A", and if "A" is empty, then output "B". This would be similar to Latex's: `\ifdefempty{\@author}{\@authora}{\oorientador}`.

```
\unprotect


\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\authora#1{\gdef\@authora{#1}}


\def\mything{
\doifemptyelse{\@author}{\@authora}{\@author}\par
}

\protect


%\author{John Doe}
\authora{Johnny Olsten}

\starttext

\mything

\stoptext
```

Comment: `\doifelse\@author\empty{\@authora}{\@author}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand `\@author` if you want to use `\doifemptyelse` as it is. Also, you need to initialise `\@author`:

```
\unprotect


\def\@author{}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\authora#1{\gdef\@authora{#1}}

\def\mything{%
\expandafter\doifemptyelse\expandafter{\@author}{\@authora}{\@author}\par
}

\protect


%\author{John Doe}
\authora{Johnny Olsten}

\starttext

\mything

\stoptext
```

Comment: So I need `expandafter` both _before_ and _after_ `doifemptyelse`... I works, but why is that (if there's a short, simple answer for that)?

Comment: @BlackBird the first `\expandafter` delays the expansion of `\doifemptyelse` and expands the second `\expandafter`. The second `\expandafter` expands `\@author` before the brace is "expanded" (well, a group-begin token doesn't expand), without the second `\expandafter` the first one would hit the opening brace instead of `\@author`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, now it's a bit clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach.

ConTeXt provides `\getparameters[<prefix>][<key>=<value>]` so you automatically create `\@author` and `\@authora`. Thus, `\mything` will only print `\@authora` when `\@author` is undefined. This will works if you don't need to work with a previously defined `\@author`.

```
\unprotect
\def\mything{\doifdefinedelse{@author}{\@author}{\@authora}}
\protect
\starttext

%This defines \@authora
\getparameters[@][authora=Mammals]
%\@author is still undefined
\mything %Mammals

%This defines \@author
\getparameters[@][author=Birds and reptiles]
\mything %Birds and reptiles

%This redefines \@author and \@authora
\getparameters[@][author=A. U. Thor, authora=A. U. Thora]
\mything %A. U. Thor

%You can also use \@author and \@authora 

\getvalue{@author} %A. U. Thor

\getvalue{@authora}%A. U. Thora

%What if I want to clear an author field?
\letvalue{@author}=\undefined

\mything %A. U. Thora

\stoptext
```

If you want to stick to LaTeX syntax a wrapper (such as `\def\author#1{\getparameters[@][author=#1]}`) isn't difficult to write, but it's certainly more verbose and useless. In such a case you have Skillmon's solution. IMHO you should get rid of those `@`s, but *de gustibus non est disputandum*.

Comment: I can see how it works. However, I still wonder how it would work in a situation in which the end user inputs the macros (such as a feminine/masculine grammatical choice) as either `author` _or_ `authorb`. What I had in mind was languages in which you get: "Autor: A" and "Autora: B", and the user would just write `\autor{A}` or `\autora{B}`. And I'd gladly red rid or `@`s for good.

Comment: Lines `\def\author#1{\getparameters[@][author=#1]}` and `\def\authora#1{\getparameters[@][authora=#1]}` in your preamble just after `\def\mything...` should do the work. Sorry, I deleted older comments as I understood something different.